# Xcode 11.1 crashes on launch - assertion failure

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, ios13, beta

Every since updating to xcode 11.1GM I cannot launch xcode without it crashing.  It comes up with 'xcode quit unexpectedly' report,  I believe the bit relevant to me is this:

```
Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information:
ASSERTION FAILURE in /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/DVTFrameworks/DVTFrameworks-15510/DVTFoundation/Assertions/DVTSoftAssertions.m:128
Details:  No path for file: LibrariesExemptedFromTriage.plist
Function: NSArray * _Nonnull _PlistDataFromFile(NSString * _Nonnull __strong)
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7fa899d02890>{number = 1, name = main}
```

However I do not know how to get around this.  Searching online shows nothing for this error.  My system is up to date, and I have since tried downloading the entire xcode 11.2 beta released today, however still cannot launch due to this error.

I have been stuck for 2 days, unable to continue development.

Comment: Try deleting `Xcode.app` from the applications folder and then reinstall it from the App Store. If that works, you could try the beta again. See also here: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/117363

Comment: Any other workarounds

Comment: For me on Xcode 13 this was related to opening an old project. If I create a new project, it will open.